# Change textViews when they equal each other?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have two textViews in my app right now. One textView serves as a Counter and the other servers as the Limit. What I want to accomplish is when the Counter equals the Limit, the Counter is set back to ZERO and the Limit is increased by 100.

```
private int i = 0;
Spinner spinnerMonsters = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerMonsters);
TextView textViewBattleResults = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewBattleResults);
TextView textViewXPValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewXPValue);
TextView textViewXpNextLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewXpNextLevel);


        if (textViewXPValue.getText().toString().equals(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString())) {
            int newLimit = Integer.parseInt(textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString()) + 100;
            textViewXpNextLevel.setText(newLimit + "");
            textViewXPValue.setText("0");
        }

        else {
            textViewXPValue.setText(textViewXPValue.getText().toString());
            textViewXpNextLevel.getText().toString();           
        }

        //Monster sequences

        if (spinnerMonsters.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("(0) Training Dummy")) {
            textViewBattleResults.setText("You have killed Training Dummy for 10 experience points!");
            i = i+10;
            textViewXPValue.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        else {
            textViewBattleResults.setText(" ");
            textViewXPValue.setText(textViewXPValue.getText().toString());
            }

        if (spinnerMonsters.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("(2) Cockroach")) {
            textViewBattleResults.setText("You have killed a Cockroach for 27 experience points!");
            i = i+27;
            textViewXPValue.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        else {
            textViewBattleResults.setText(" ");
            textViewXPValue.setText(textViewXPValue.getText().toString());
            }



        }


    });
```

The problem here is that the counter will count up by ten when the button is clicked. But when the Counter equals the Limit, the Limit increases by 100 and the Counter remains at the same number and doesn't reset back to ZERO.

Any suggestions..?

**EDIT**

Also, how would i do the same thing but if the Counter was Equal to or Greater than the Limit?

Comment: it seems that it's not full code. Where do you increase counter by 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't reset value of i to zero. You first set text of xpvalue to zero, but then you set it's text to current value ofi, which is not zero.

Comment: wow so simple... and do you know how i would change it so if the Counter was over the Limit, it would also reset? like Counter = 137 and the Limit = 100?

Comment: convert value of xpNextLevel to int and compare it to i instead of checking that text of xpvalue and xpNextLevel are equal

Comment: @CoreyWilliams your implementation is somehow flawed, views should only display data to the user and not hold the data for them, the math should be as simple as checking whether `(137 > 100)`, let the values of the `counter` and `limit` be stored in `int` and only update the relevant views when this data changes.